# Proving $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n}}\sum_{r=0}^{n}\frac{1}{2^{4r}}\binom{2r}{r}^2=\frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{\pi}}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, summation, elliptic-integrals

Infinite Sum :

$$S=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n}}\sum_{r=0}^{n}\frac{1}{2^{4r}}\binom{2r}{r}^2$$

This Sum could be said to be related to Moments of Elliptic Integrals as we have :
$$\int_{0}^{1}k^{2r}K'(k)dk=\frac{\pi^{2}}{4}\binom{2r}{r}^2\frac{1}{2^{4r}}$$
Where, $K(k)$ is the Complete Elliptical Integral of the First Kind and $K'(k)=K(k')$ with $k^2+k'^2=1$.

Using this one can arrive at the following Integral :
$$S=\frac{16}{\pi^{2}}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{K'(k)}{2-k^{2}}dk$$

or the Equivalent using Quadratic Transformation:
$$S=\frac{32}{\pi^{2}}\int_{0}^{1}K(k)\left(\frac{1+k}{k^{2}+6k+1}\right)dk$$

But I have been unable to evaluate any of these Integrals.

I suspect it might have a closed form as does its similar cousin :

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(2n+1\right)^{2}}\sum_{r=0}^{n}\frac{1}{2^{4r}}\binom{2r}{r}^{2}=\frac{7}{2}\frac{\zeta(3)}{\pi}$$

EDIT:
After Inputting the Value into Wolfram we get this :

$$S=\frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{\pi}}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2$$

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Evaluate $S$ as a [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product), using the [generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient#Generating_function) for the squared central binomial coefficient:

$$\begin{align*}
S &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac1{2^n} \sum_{r=0}^{n} \frac{1}{2^{4r}} \binom{2r}{r}^2 \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{r=0}^{n} \frac{1}{2^{n-r}} \cdot \frac1{2^{5r}} \binom{2r}r^2 \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac1{2^{5i}} \binom{2i}i^2 \cdot \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac1{2^j} \\
&= \frac{16-8\sqrt2}{\pi} K\left(\frac{\sqrt2-1}{\sqrt2+1}\right) \\
&= \frac{16-8\sqrt2}{\pi} \cdot \frac{(\sqrt2+1)\Gamma\left(\frac14\right)^2}{8\sqrt{2\pi}} \\
&= \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac14\right)^2}{\pi^{3/2}} 
\end{align*}$$

where $K(k)=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2t}}$. The conversion from $K$ to $\Gamma$ in the penultimate step relies on a formula mentioned in the Borweins' [*Pi and the AGM*](http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/%7Epborwein/TEMP_PROTECTED/pi-agm.pdf#page=155) (see *Evaluation of $K$ in terms of $\Gamma$* at the bottom of p.296) but the exact details elude me.

Comment: Amazing Solution! In your last steps we can directly use $$\frac{4}{\pi}K(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$$, and the elliptical singular moduli are well known.
As a sidenote, I am unable to proceed further if let's say we change $2^{n}$ to something else. Any hints on that?

Comment: @MiracleInvoker Depends on the "something else", I imagine.

Answer (score 2):

*Too long for comments.*

$$A_n=\sum_{r=0}^{n}\frac{1}{2^{4r}}\binom{2r}{r}^2=\frac {a_n}{b_n}$$

Numerators and denominators form sequences $A277233$ and $A056982$ in $OEIS$

$$B_m=\sum_{n=0}^{m}\frac{1}{2^{n}}\,\sum_{r=0}^{n}\frac{1}{2^{4r}}\binom{2r}{r}^2=\frac {c_m}{d_m}$$

Denominators form sequence $A130034$ in $OEIS$ but, for numerators
$$\{1,13,505,4421,591497,4838381,156584033,1259879669,646944895433\}
$$ $OEIS$ does not find anything.

Using inverse symbolic calculators, nothing found for
$$2.3606811980321924520906758811169771744674332697629\cdots$$

Comment: Thank you for the efforts, I realized this value equals :
$$\frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{\pi}}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2$$

Comment: @MiracleInvoker. How did you fid this beauty ?

Comment: $$A_n=\sum_{r=0}^{n}\frac{1}{2^{4r}}\binom{2r}{r}^2=\frac{\Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \, _3F_2\left(1,-n,-n;\frac{1}{2}-n,\frac{1}{2}-n;1\right)}{\pi  \Gamma (n+1)^2}$$ :)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I put the value into Wolfram, from my experience it finds values related to the Lemniscate and Ubiquitous Constants quite easily.

Comment: @MiracleInvoker. Could you give me the syntax ? Thanks & cheers

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk. Thank you

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I just put the value into Wolfram Alpha and it gave the result.

Comment: @MiracleInvoker. Give me what you type in WA, please

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I meant the default "Possible Closed Forms" Panel
You can paste "2.3606811980321924520906758811169771744674332697629" into Wolfram Alpha and it will give it in terms of Ubiquitous Constant.